# replacing special characters in recordset access vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using input tables with special chars, but my output tables need to be without them.
So i need function that would replace special chars in query or table 
for example

> Š=S Č=C Ć=C Ž=Z

Any sugestions?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024072/how-to-remove-accents-and-all-chars-a-z-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You could pop them into a string, and then use Replace, e.g. `strYourString = Replace(strYourString, "Š","S")`.

Downside of this approach is you'd need to specify all the special characters you want to replace, and run the code several times, perhaps as a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Replace function does that but (as far as I know) for single character:
Expr1: Replace([Employees].[Prezime];"č";"c")
For a fast but not efficiant solution you can create several fileds named Expr1, Expr2 Expr3, and in each remove one special character.
But I am searching for more "decent" solution.