# how to get data from sql server encoded in UTF8?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, encoding, utf-8

i want to get data from sql server data base encoded in utf8 encoding

i have looked into it i found this answer : [Is it possible to have SQL Server convert collation to UTF-8 / UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281105/is-it-possible-to-have-sql-server-convert-collation-to-utf-8-utf-16) , i used collation utf8_unicode_ci  in the query like this :

```
 select code collation utf8_unicode_ci  from testTable where code = 33;
```

i got an error , i also found this link : [Convert output of MySQL query to utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051369/convert-output-of-mysql-query-to-utf8), used this query :

```
select  CONVERT(CAST(code as BINARY) USING utf8) as code from testTable where code = 33;
```

but i get  "ï»¿" at beginning of the output file . im lost now

Comment: *"I got error"* doesn't tell us much. I assume, as you tried to use a UTF8 collation, that your using an RC version of SQL Server 2019?

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: Can you share the sample data you have stored in SQL Server database? And also share what exact output do you get with different query approaches you used.

Comment: the error that i got was this : collation 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid

Comment: Once you take a bytes array an using UTF8 encoding you can't fix the issue by converting to UTF16.  You may be able to take the UTF8 and convert to a byte[] and then take the byte[] and encode in UTF16.  For example UTF8 encoding will change the 0x80 bytes and you will not be able to undo the change.

Comment: the data i have is simple a table called test table it has 2 columns : code and date

Comment: If that collation is invalid then you aren't using SQL Server 2019. Earlier versions do not support UTF-8.

Comment: well what should i do , im working locally now but when i deliver my solution to different clients they will have different versions of sql server , i need something to convert the data in the client side so it will be generic

Comment: that is why i wanted to edit the query so it gets the data encoded in utf8  encoding independent from what sql serve version they have

Comment: if there is anothere way in code im all ears

Comment: @ jdweng i dont want utf16 just need to convert data to that i got from a query to utf8

Comment: Please [edit] to show how C# and an output file are involved.