# Replace accent with upper and lowercase

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

Have a table of customers with accented letters, I need to replace them with the same letter without the accent, I can use the REPLACE feature, but my problem is that I have some clients in upper case and some in lower case and I need keep uppercase and lowercase

Comment: What language are you using? SQL?

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry forgot that...

Comment: Then tag you question ([edit]) accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024072/how-to-remove-accents-and-all-chars-a-z-in-sql-server

Comment: If you need the upper case, replace them for upper case equivalents. Do the same for the lowercase.

Comment: Ok Consider Me, like this: "UPDATE YourTable SET col =
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
 ,'á','a'),'Á','A'),'é','e'),'Ã','A'),'ê','e')"

Comment: I'm using SQL Server a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1032/case-sensitive-search-on-a-case-insensitive-sql-server/

Comment: @MikeTex I've included my answer. It needs a change of collation for your column. Try it out and reply back under my answer if this works for all of your diacritics.

Comment: @MikeTex could I shed some light into it? Is the solution proposed not working?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, your expected result could be achieved using `REPLACE()` function.

If you need to **preserve upper and lower case** letters, then write explicitly replace functions for both cases **AND** change the collation to case-sensitive one: `Latin1_General_CS_AS`.

[Here is the related post on using this collation for case sensitive search.](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/) and a quote from it:

> Adding COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS makes the search case sensitive.

Using your example characters from comments, that are in the input below it seems to be working.

**Query**

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('áÁéÃ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'á','a'),'Á','A'),'é','e'),'Ã','A')
```

Input: `áÁéÃ`

Output: `aAeA`

Check <kbd>**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6709)**</kbd> to view the example in action.