# How can I perform Data Cleaning and substite unicode (LATIN) carachters with US English characters

Tags: c#, t-sql

Is there a way to perform data cleaning and identify LATIN characters such as Á (and similar) and convert them to the nearest US English chars (in this case, 'A')?

I prefer to do this directly in TSQL code, but if its not possible, I am willing to employ other options such as any C# method.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

I have hundreds of thousands records in a table. that data entries have such mistakes, these are causing problems which breaks the code..

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12715102/1080354 You can simply convert the data in the T-SQL :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: (Thanks to @gotqn in the comments)
[stackoverflow.com/a/12715102/1080354](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12715102/1080354)

```
SELECT 'héllö! this is à test!' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI
```

result:

```
hello! this is a test!
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Updated Anwer (20120212):**

Though my answer below will work, and considering that T-SQL TRANSLATE is especially fast, what gotn posted and David's answer above will perform much better.

It's worth noting (I just learned this) that both `Cyrillic_General_CI_AI` and `Greek_CI_AI` also work. This is good to know because some collations perform better than others so it's good to test.

---

### **Previous Answer**

You didn't mention what version of SQL Server you are using.

**If you are using SQL Server 2017+**

Then you can leverage [TRANSLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like so:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = 'Thë Quìck Grééñ Fox Jumps ôver The Lázy Dög.';

SELECT      NewString = TRANSLATE(@string,accents.C,clean.C)
FROM        (VALUES('áÁâÂäÄãÃàÀéÉêÊëËèÈíÍîÎïÏìÌóÓôÔöÖõÕòÒúÚûÛüÜùÙýÝñÑçÇ')) AS accents(C)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES('aAaAaAaAaAeEeEeEeEiIiIiIiIoOoOoOoOoOuUuUuUuUyYnNcC')) AS clean(C);
```

**Returns:** The Quick Green Fox Jumps over The Lazy Dog.

**If you are using an earlier version of SQL**

For this you can leverage [NGrams8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) to create your own TRANSLATE function which I include at the end of this post.

```
SELECT      t.NewString
FROM        (VALUES('áÁâÂäÄãÃàÀéÉêÊëËèÈíÍîÎïÏìÌóÓôÔöÖõÕòÒúÚûÛüÜùÙýÝñÑçÇ')) AS accents(C)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES('aAaAaAaAaAeEeEeEeEiIiIiIiIoOoOoOoOoOuUuUuUuUyYnNcC')) AS clean(C)
CROSS APPLY samd.translate8K(@string,accents.C,clean.C)     AS t;
```

Here is the code I used to generate the string of accent characters:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  CHAR(225),CHAR(193),CHAR(226),CHAR(194),CHAR(228),CHAR(196),CHAR(227),CHAR(195),CHAR(224),CHAR(192), -- a(10)
  CHAR(233),CHAR(201),CHAR(234),CHAR(202),CHAR(235),CHAR(203),CHAR(232),CHAR(200),                     -- e(8)
  CHAR(237),CHAR(205),CHAR(238),CHAR(206),CHAR(239),CHAR(207),CHAR(236),CHAR(204),                     -- i(8)
  CHAR(243),CHAR(211),CHAR(244),CHAR(212),CHAR(246),CHAR(214),CHAR(245),CHAR(213),CHAR(242),CHAR(210), -- o(10)
  CHAR(250),CHAR(218),CHAR(251),CHAR(219),CHAR(252),CHAR(220),CHAR(249),CHAR(217),                     -- u(8)
  CHAR(253),CHAR(221),CHAR(241),CHAR(209),CHAR(231),CHAR(199))                               -- y(2),n(2),c(2)
```

**Custom Translate Function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION samd.translate8K
(
  @inputString  VARCHAR(8000), 
  @characters   VARCHAR(8000), 
  @translations VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN
/*****************************************************************************************
[Purpose]: Custom version of SQL Server 2017 Translate

-- Masking possible PII
DECLARE @inputstring VARCHAR(8000) = 
  'I don''t know if you got my SSN but it''s 555-90-5511. Call me at 312.800.5555';

SELECT t.newstring
FROM   samd.translate8K(@inputString, '0123456789', REPLICATE('#',10)) AS t;

[Revision History]:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Rev 00 - 20180725 - Initial Development - Alan Burstein
****************************************************************************************/
SELECT newstring = 
(
  SELECT      CASE WHEN c.chr>c.tx THEN '' WHEN c.chr>0 THEN t.chr ELSE ng.token END+''
  FROM        samd.NGrams8k(@inputString,1)                                 AS ng 
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(ng.token, @characters),LEN(@translations))) AS c(chr,tx)
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(@translations,c.chr,1)))                    AS t(chr)
  ORDER BY ng.position
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('text()[1]', 'varchar(8000)');
GO
```

https://emw3.com/unicode-accents.html