# SQL Query to find and replace with the normal string character

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2016

I have imported the data into my DB but found the special characters in my company names.

The Special characters are as  below

*special character*

`Alecta PensionsfÃ¶rsÃ¤kring, Ã¶msesidigt`

*Normal character*

`Alecta Pensionsforsakring,Omsesidigt`

*special character*

`AelefÃ³nica, S.A.`

*Normal character*

`Aelefonica,S.A.`

I have tried with replace method with hardcoded special characters but in the real data...contains 1000's of records and it's very difficult for me to keep the hardcoded values... Kindly provide me a SQL dynamic query which will find out the special characters in a string.

Comment: Column data type? Typical encoding issue.

Comment: Maybe you need to re-import the data with the right encoding / codepage / collation at all steps.

Comment: How does the file contents look? File encoding?

Comment: In source we can't modify the script and the packages are automated. The only approach we have is from the data base level by using the SQL scripts need to modify the company names

Comment: Even if you can't do anything about how it's imported *O_o* it might be still usefull to know what the original encoding was. Btw, could it be that the column is a VARCHAR (instead of NVARCHAR)

Comment: Looks like utf vs ascii issues, I guess the correct spelling is `pensionsförsäkring` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The original encoding is probably UTF-8.

So you can use a UDF to make it more readable.

*The UDF is based on [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53459210/4003419) from [Xabi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10699293/xabi)*

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION Utf8ToUcs(@src varchar(MAX)) 
> RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
> WITH SCHEMABINDING
> AS
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE @i INT
>           , @res NVARCHAR(MAX)=@src
>           , @pi VARCHAR(18);
>           
>     SELECT 
>       @pi = '%[à-ï][€-¿][€-¿]%'
>     , @i = PATINDEX(@pi, @src COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN);
>  
>     WHILE @i > 0 
>       SELECT 
>         @res = STUFF(@res,@i,3, NCHAR(
>                       ((ASCII(SUBSTRING(@src,@i,1))&31)*4096)
>                      +((ASCII(SUBSTRING(@src,@i+1,1))&63)*64)
>                      +(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@src,@i+2,1))&63)))
>       , @src = STUFF(@src,@i,3,'.')
>       , @i = PATINDEX(@pi,@src COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN);
>
>     SELECT 
>       @pi = '%[Â-ß][€-¿]%'
>     , @i = PATINDEX(@pi,@src COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN);
>
>     WHILE @i > 0 
>       SELECT 
>         @res = STUFF(@res,@i,2,NCHAR(
>                        ((ASCII(SUBSTRING(@src,@i,1))&31)*64)
>                        +(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@src,@i+1,1))&63)))
>       , @src = STUFF(@src,@i,2,'.')
>       , @i = PATINDEX(@pi,@src COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN);
>
>     RETURN @res;
> END;
> ```

> ```
> select col
> , dbo.Utf8ToUcs(col) as col_ucs
> from test
> ```

| col | col_ucs |
| --- | --- |
| Alecta PensionsfÃ¶rsÃ¤kring, Ã¶msesidigt | Alecta Pensionsförsäkring, ömsesidigt |
| AelefÃ³nica, S.A. | Aelefónica, S.A. |
| Áæâàéêèeeeëöu | Áæâàéêèeeeëöu |

And then you can also remove the accents.
Here's it's done via a collation.  *(solution taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12715102/4003419))*

> ```
> select col
> , cast(dbo.Utf8ToUcs(col) as varchar(100)) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI as col_cp1253
> from test
> ```

| col | col_cp1253 |
| --- | --- |
| Alecta PensionsfÃ¶rsÃ¤kring, Ã¶msesidigt | Alecta Pensionsforsakring, omsesidigt |
| AelefÃ³nica, S.A. | Aelefonica, S.A. |
| Áæâàéêèeeeëöu | A?aaeeeeeeeou |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=16cb349587f853a2fd22329d30c35d56)*